# IE7 Weird spacing in ul

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

So, I'm making this context menus, which looks great in all major browsers, even IE plays nice, right down until IE7.

[image: spacing]

I don't know why it has that weird spacing and was hoping someone could enlighten me.

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XLRWT/)

CSS

```
/* CSS Document */

*{
    zoom: 1;
}    

.context-menu-container{
    border: 1px solid #828790;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    font-family: 'MS Sans Serif', Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.context-menu{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.context-menu li{
    position: relative;
    height: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.context-menu li.separator{
    height: 2px;
    border: 0;
    background: url(http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/2599/horizontalseparator.png) repeat-x center;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-left: 26px;
}

.context-menu li.separator:hover{
    border: 0;
    background: url(http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/2599/horizontalseparator.png) repeat-x center;
}

.context-menu li:hover{
    border: 1px solid #afd0f7;
    background: url(http://img860.imageshack.us/img860/3511/contextmenuhover.png) repeat-x;
}

.context-menu li.disabled, .context-menu li.disabled a{
    color: #8b8b8b;
}

.context-menu li.disabled:hover{
    border: 1px solid #d5d4d4;
    background: url(http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/31/contextmenudisabled.png) repeat-x;
}

.context-menu li a{
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    cursor: default;
    padding-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

.context-menu a.delete{
    background: url(http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/9831/deleteqb.png) no-repeat 2px center;
}

.context-menu .vertical-separator{
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    background: url(http://img836.imageshack.us/img836/6873/verticalseparator.png) repeat-y;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.context-menu div.label{
    margin-left: 25px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    float:left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class='context-menu-container'>
    <ul class='context-menu'>
        <div class='vertical-separator'></div>
        <li><a class='delete' href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li class='separator'></li>
        <li class='disabled'><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: you can't put a `<div>` as a direct child to `<ul>`

Comment: @Joseph Um, yes I can, I've been doing it for a long time, and none of the major browsers has a problem with it, from my experience. IE7 also accepts it, check out my previous question. I use a div inside a ul there as well.

Comment: although it does work, it's not recommended as the spec says [lists are made up of sequences of list items defined by the LI element (whose end tag may be omitted).](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#h-10.2)

Comment: @ShadowScripter - You *can*, but it's not in spec.  And every browser handles non-standard HTML differently. (Admitdly, IE7 handles standard HTML differently).  This is the one error I got from running your code (wrapped in a valid HTML5 body) through the w3 validator : ''`Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)`''

Comment: @Anthony While you're here, how would I get the desired effect without having the div inside the ul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this, unsurprisingly because of an IE7 bug:

```
.context-menu li.separator {
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/XLRWT/17/

Also, having a `<div>` as a child of a `<ul>` is invalid HTML. It may work in browsers, but it's [still invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fjsfiddle.net%2Fthirtydot%2FXLRWT%2F17%2Fshow%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: Wow, fixed it right up. So, what, it calculates a spacing for a font and an inherited line height even though it has no content or something? What's the bug about? xD

Comment: Hm, so because it's invalid, I shouldn't use it, although it works on all the browsers? Then how am I supposed to get the desired effect... Sigh, designing made overcomplicated.

Comment: So it's the empty list item? Ha!  @ShadowScripter - It's not overly complicated, it just more than design. If it was just about design (and not information architecture, etc), then we could have stuck with tables.  But I think it should be easier, if you're willing to let it fail in some older browsers (hard for the visual visionaries to do, I know).  You basically have drop the `div` and the empty `li` and use positioned background images for two of the items. I think you could maybe pull off using borders for the items with some alpha channels and beveled drop shadow. I'm going to try.

Comment: @ShadowScripter: I think this is the same, using an `li` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/XLRWT/19/. Some refactoring would make it cleaner.

Comment: @thirtydot didn't know you could do the same thing with an `li`. Now there's no errors, woo! Thanks. I'll be refactoring after I'm done with the plugin.

Comment: @ShadowScripter - Here's what I came up with. http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/ZCZtQ/ No wrapper div or inner div. Let me know if it crashes and burns badly in any browsers. It uses multiple background images in one spot and box shadows to achieve the embossed effect, so I'm not sure if >IE9 will work.

Comment: @Anthony Your suspicions are correct. The hover for the delete action doesn't work properly in >IE9 and the separator borders are off by 1-2 px to the left as well. Only IE though. Silly browser. Chrome and Firefox renders it beautifully tho. I should probably point out that placing a horizontal separator with that setup will be more difficult than just placing a div and giving it a separator class. With the HTML approach to separators you can also use server generated menus', but not with the CSS approach. Yours does however have a more.. "Clean" feel to it.

Comment: @ShadowScripter - Another drawback is that the vertical separator, in addition to forcing the list items to be smaller than the links, is that the list items can't have any margin between them (only padding) or else the the horizontal "line" becomes separated. Or is that what you meant by the 1-2 px?  It would be okay to set the ul border as the vertical border and set the background color and border on the wrapper nav/menu element, I suppose.  Then you could go back to using the delete image on the link and the hover halo on the list items.

Comment: @Anthony is there a way to perhaps get the same "line" effect but within an individual list item? I mean, without using an image background. Also, I did not mean the spacing between the list items, but a general shift to the left. It's basically crashing in with the vertical separator

Comment: @ShadowScripter - Do you mean for the vertical or the horizontal separator (the "line" effect)?  Instead of using the background images, I instead did two side-by-side 1px borders with the colors of your images.  For the horizontals, this was just doing the bottom border one color and the top another. For the vertical, because there was no "left side" to put a border on, I used the box-shadow effect and offset it by one pixel.  You can email or gchat me using my profile email if you want to take this offline.